# translate shell how to get original language of the text?

Tags: linux, shell, translate

How can I get the original language of the text?

I know I can use -id and that is showing the Name, Family, Writing system, Code etc but I need only the Code from this list.

```
trans -id  "how are you today?" -no-auto
```

So if I write the above thing in shell I get this list and I want only know the Code (en):

> Name                  English
>
> Family                Indo-European
>
> Writing system        Latin
>
> Code                  en
>
> ISO 639-3             eng
>
> SIL                   https://iso639-3.sil.org/code/eng
>
> Glottolog
> https://glottolog.org/resource/languoid/id/stan1293
>
> Wikipedia             https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639:eng

Comment: When pasting exact output from a piece of software, consider using a code segment for that so the exact formatting is preserved. Start one (with no syntax highlighting) with a line having only three backticks immediately followed by the word `none` (no spaces); end it with a line having three backticks and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ trans -id  "how are you today?" -no-auto | grep Code | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: No need to use `grep`.  This works `trans -id  "how are you today?" -no-auto | awk '/^Code/ {print $2}'`